# Right click contextual menu seems to have disappeared for one use on Mac OS X El Capitan 10.11.5

Tags: macos, mac, mouse, context-menu

So I think this problem might be one of cumulative upgrades & benign neglect.  This machine (used Mid 2011 iMac 27" iMac12,2 Intel Corei7 3.4 Ghz) is my wife's newest Mac in a long line that began with with an iBook, MacBook & several Mac Mini's.  I'm guilty of simply migrating her old information and account to each new machine as it was installed.  This one being the same.  However something is missing…  right click mouse features when you right click.  I've gone into mouse settings (its a blue tooth magic mouse) and clicked the box for right click features to no avail.  I switched the mouse - no change.  I logged into other accounts on the disk (also migrated each time) and tested.  The administrator's mouse settings work as expected.  Another non-administrator account (mine) fails to work properly also.

I'm perplexed, to my knowledge I've never done anything in Terminal on her machines over the years other than look around, and in fact have no idea where/how to interact with mouse settings other than in the standard settings window.

Any suggestions to point the way. This iMac is now the only machine that's young enough to upgrade to the new "MacOS" being released these days.
Thank you all in advance - clgworks.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried deleting the com.apple.Bluetooth.plist file from Preferences?
  Open your Library/Preferences and find the file in that list. 
  Copy it somewhere safe, and then delete the file from Preferences.
  Restart your Mac with the mouse plugged in(**) and no file in Preferences.

It should create the file from scratch.

(**) by plugged in, I was thinking of a USB mouse when I answered this.  I'd delete the file and try with a basic USB mouse first (since you have one), and then try loading the magic mouse on again.